# nativeClang and nativeClang not found. I installed llvm to my path and used giter8 for the project but the program is failing. How do I fix this?

Tags: scala-native

Error looks like this:

[error] (nativeClang) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[error] (nativeClangPP) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows?

scala-native is supported on POSIX like operating systems (like Linux, macOS, FreeBSD).

Please, see the list of supported OS, at the end of this page:

https://scala-native.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.9-docs/user/setup.html